# Array reduce return boolean in variable

Tags: php, arrays

How I can return boolean type in variable? I have code:

```
$imageRes = array_reduce(['image', 'image1', 'image2'], function ($carry) {
    return in_array($carry, ['image1', 'image2']);
});
```

I need `return` in `imageRes` a boolean type: true/false, if one of the elements in `['image1', 'image2']` is in `['image', 'image1', 'image2']`. How I can do it?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Eddie I need return result of `in_array` in variable $imageRes

Comment: Yes, but what is the logic? Are you trying to check if element 0 is same either with element 1 or 2?

Comment: @Eddie Yep. I need check on `image1`, `image2`

Comment: why not `$a[0] === $a[1]  || $a[0] === $a[2]`?

Comment: @Eddie I can do and like so. But how I can return result true/false in `$imageRes`

Comment: Yes, `$imageRes = $a[0] === $a[1] || $a[0] === $a[2];`

Comment: @Eddie ahh no.. I can have multiple values in array.. I can have 100 images in random position

Comment: but you only want to check the first element against the 99?

Comment: @Eddie No. I want check for value = image1, image2, I can and check for image5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array-intersect) instead of `array_reduce()`, count the result of that and cast it to a boolean. If there are no intersections, the `count()` will be zero, thus a boolean `false`. If there are at least one value intersecting, the `count()` will be greater than one and any non-zero number cast to a boolean will be `true`.

```
$imageRes = (bool)count(array_intersect(['image1', 'image2'], ['image', 'image1', 'image2']));
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/0INUP
- [PHP.net on `array_intersect()`](http://php.net/array-intersect)

Comment: I don't need return array in `$imageRes` I need return only true/false.

Comment: So you want it to be `true` if just one of the elements in the array is in the smaller array?

Comment: Yep. You right... I need return true if element of array was found

Comment: See my revised answer.

Comment: Why not `(bool) array_intersect(['image1', 'image2'], ['image', 'image1', 'image2']);` ? Why We need use `count` ?

Comment: You can actually do without it, as an array with values is truthy.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to know if any of the elements are in both arrays use `array_intersect()`, count the result and cast to boolean(`!!`)

```
$ref_array = ['image1', 'image2'];
$array = ['image', 'image1', 'image2'];
$imageRes = !!count(array_intersect($array, $ref_array));
var_dump($imageRes);
```

Comment: You can also achieve it by doing `!array_diff()` - there's many ways to Rome.. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution with `array_reduce` would be like this:

```
$imageRes = array_reduce(
    ['image', 'image1', 'image2',], 
    function($carry, $item) {
        return $carry || in_array($item, ['image1', 'image2']);
    },
    false //Initial value is false
);
```